# CPU USAGE on cPanel

Tags: php, hosting, cpu-usage

I have a host to 'JustHost' and I had a problem with a PHP-Class. They have suspended my account with the following reason: *Just Host offer unlimited hosting space and unlimited bandwidth, but as per our terms we will suspend any website which exceeds our 10% CPU/MEM/MySQL policy.*

Well, I made a custom class to find the CPU-Usage

```
<?php
$LoadAvg = substr(file_get_contents('/proc/loadavg'), 0, 4);
echo $LoadAvg > 10 ? "Server busy, try again later." : "$LoadAvg % CPU USAGE";
?>
```

My question is:
The class will show the total CPU Usage of the **entire server** or only my **cPanel** ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will show you the cpu usage of all sites hosted on that particular server of theirs.

Answer (score 0):

Load averages do not equate to CPU utilization. What is measures is the number of processes in contention for CPU time.

On a shared server, its hard to get a precise measurement of CPU utilization.

Comment: I need only an idea about CPU, not exactly. Thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

As i know ,WHM CPanel is some kind of Web Application in PHP Language for Controlling system witch have some tools for Web Server Administrator to keep track of accounts(Users or Groups) and make automated of DNS setting and do some Virtual-Directories and Install some additional software through a Website and so on .

My point is it is not some thing we could divide from OS for example Cent OS Linux to see it's CPU average . what you saw was overall CPU usage of that specific Server .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but in order to make daily CPU / RAM consumption available for my CPanel users I make simple script shell that creates daily file named `<login>-cpu.html`, and put it in user `public_html`.

The script is available at: http://50dh.info/create-daily-cpu-peruser.txt

You can easily add suspension if limit are raised.